# "Shop by Brand" extesion of "mazeplaza" not showing frontend pages

Tags: magento2.2.2

I am using "shop by brand" extension of "Mazeplaza". But it is not working and slow down my website from frontend and backend. None of the pages regarding brands loading in frontend. I have more than 30,000 products in website.